# Dockerize rmi application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I'm new to Docker and I would like to put my rmi server on docker and to access it using the client which is local, on the laptop. When the server is not on docker the application works, however when it is on docker, I get a "Connection Refused" error. Below is the code for the server:

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import ro.tuc.ds2020.services.MedicationPlanService;
import ro.tuc.ds2020.servinterface.IMedicationService;


import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.util.*;

@SpringBootApplication
@Validated
public class Ds2020Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {
    private int port;
    // private Registry registry;





    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Ds2020Application.class);
    }





    public Ds2020Application() throws RemoteException{

        this.port = 8889;

        Registry registry = null;
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(this.port);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            //MedicationPlanService is the stub // "name",stub
            registry.bind(IMedicationService.class.getSimpleName(), new MedicationPlanService());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        try {
          
            SpringApplication.run(Ds2020Application.class, args);
        
            System.out.println("The server has started.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }





    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

and client:

```
package ro.tuc.ds2020.controller;



import ro.tuc.ds2020.DTO.DrugPlanDTO;
import ro.tuc.ds2020.servinterface.IMedicationService;
import ro.tuc.ds2020.view.DisplayTable;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClientController {
    private static IMedicationService iMedicationService;
    private Registry registry;
    private String serverAddress;
    private int serverPort;
    private DisplayTable displayTable;

    public ClientController() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException, SQLException, ParseException {
        this.serverAddress = "localhost";
        this.serverPort = 8889;
        String patientID="334975ea-c90d-4fd2-9a0b-9e2c9f0e4cb9";
        //obtain the stub for the registry
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress, serverPort);
        //obtain stub for remote object from server registry
        iMedicationService = (IMedicationService) (registry.lookup(IMedicationService.class.getSimpleName()));
       ArrayList<DrugPlanDTO> dto= iMedicationService.getAllMedicationPlans(patientID);
       for (DrugPlanDTO drugplans:
                dto) {
            System.out.println((String)drugplans.getBegin_time());
        }
            this.displayTable=new DisplayTable(dto,patientID);

            System.out.println("Finished");

    }

    public static void sendMessage(String drugPlanID,String patientID,String medicationName,String begin_time,String end_time) throws RemoteException, SQLException {



        if (iMedicationService != null) {
            iMedicationService.savePillTakenLog(drugPlanID,patientID,medicationName,begin_time,end_time);
            System.out.println("Finished send message"+ patientID);
        }
    }


}
```

Im not sure how to bind the client to the server when dockerizing the application.
Docker compose:

```
version: '3'

services:

  tomcat-db-api:
    image: ds_a3
    ports:
       - "8889:8889"

  rabbitmq-container:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
     - 5672:5672
     - 15672:15672
```

Comment: can you share the dockerfile and the command you run to start it

Comment: You need open ports for rmi to work.

Comment: @Alex added the docker compose file , I start it using docker build -t ds_a3 . and then using docker compose-up -d

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen can't find any tutorial related to this, a hint please?

Comment: @simm You need to read up on how RMI works.  I do not have experience on running the RMI server in a separate docker container.

Comment: First, just to clear up the easy part: are the server and client both running on your laptop, i.e., `localhost`?

Comment: @erickson the server is on docker and the client locally

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the: `this.serverAddress="tomcat-db-api;"` at your client.